# How to connect the Redux's store and actions to React's components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have some experience with ReactJS but now I am trying to start using Redux and I have encoutered several problems. I already know how to create actions, consts, reducers, how to connect them to one single store, but I don't actually now how to use it with React. For example I have a form to gather user's data and I want it all passed to Redux store. So I guess the main question would be how do I trigger the action in ReactJS?

Comment: Short answer is: If you need to ask you most likely don't need to use Redux. It will bring more problems for you than it will solve.

Comment: @PetrPeller I'm not sure I agree. Needing redux and not knowing how to use it in React are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @TastesLikeTurkey Sure, but the way the question was asked suggests there is no need for Redux. You should only use Redux if you know what exact problems you have that it can solve. And "I need to use a state management framework" is not one those.

Comment: @PetrPeller Fair enough, perhaps the question was edited before I saw it? Because I don't think we can make a judgment on whether he ought to be using Redux based off of one page of his site. I just don't like the direction SO seems to have gone recently, from "here's an answer to the question you asked" to "here's why you shouldn't be asking your question."

Comment: @TastesLikeTurkey True, I don't like that direction too but mostly in the actual answers. I think it's fine to suggest an alternative approach in comments though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when using `react-redux`, you'll get a component enhancer called `connect`.

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onClickButton}>
        {this.props.a}
      </button>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(function mapStateToProps(state) { 
  return { a: state.store.a } 
}, { onClickButton: incrementAction })(Component)
```

What I'm doing here is taking a global store value (`state.store.a` - `state` is the global store, `.store` is the store from a combined store, and `a` is the value), and telling the React component to listen for changes on this variable (transparently through `connect`).

Additionally, I'm wrapping an action creator `incrementAction` (and renaming it to `onClickButton`). If you're using a middleware like `redux-thunk`, this will automatically pass in `store.dispatch` as an arg. Otherwise, this is a standard action creator.

both of these will be available inside the component as props (the args are descriptively named `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`)

Comment: the thing I missed was the connect part, thank you very much for that

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux). For example, here's a small counter:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { increment } from "actions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";

function counter ({ count, increment }) {
  return <button onClick={increment}>
    {count}
  </button>;
}

counter.propTypes = {
  count: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  increment: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    count: state.data.count
  }),
  { increment }
)(counter);
```

The `(state) => ({ })` bit passes a property called `count` to the component's props. The `{ increment }` passes your `increment` function in the props.

Be sure to include the `{ increment }` part in the `connect`; if you don't, your redux action won't be dispatched.

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to edit yours. thought I was editing my answer D:

Comment: I am new user on stackoverflow, can I close the question? :D

Comment: accept an answer which helped you, that "closes" the question

Comment: @LiudasD You should accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. Personally I'd suggest Tyler's, as it gives more detail on what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

To bind redux to react there is a package called [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux). The description of which is official react bindings for redux.

You can connect the actions to react by using `mapDispatchToProps`, which will map your actions as props. Then you can call those actions as props. When you call those actions as props, the actions will be triggered and redux state will change.

To access the state you have to use `mapStateToProps`, which will give you the state as props.

You can use `connect` method to connect `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` to react.

I think it would be easier if you do a tutorial. [This](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) is a tutorial by Dan Abramov, creator of Redux.

Comment: I know this and I have installed it, but how do I trigger actions? I have checked that page and went through the tutorial, but I still couldn't manage it